# Excel Chart Y-Axis (Formatted as Fraction) Label Alignment

Tags: excel, charts

Please see the below image. It is a snip containing the Y-axis of a chart I have created in Excel 2007.

[image]

The number format for the Y-axis is:

**Category: *Fraction***

**Type: *Up to one digit (1/4)***

**Format Code: *# ?/?***

I would like to **right-align** the labels on the Y-axis such that the 0 and 1 values appear in vertical alignment with 4, 2, 4 but have not been able to do so. When I select the Y-axis in the chart and click Right Align in the Excel Ribbon nothing happens.

**Is it possible to right-align the Y-axis labels through formatting alone and if not can someone propose an alternative solution?**

As ever many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using the Format Code: `[=0]0;[=1]#;?/?`